# Scaling y-axis appropriate to data in multiple line chart display

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The multiple line chart example at https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_smallmultiple.html quite clearly provides the examples I need for what I'm trying to do...

except...

I need the y-axis scale for each of the charts to be appropriate for the data associated with the individual keys.  As is, the example does d3.max on the entire data set, not the filtered data set controlling the individual lines.

I've tried various ways to apply the filter in the y-axis definition and can't get anything to work.

The closest I've been able to get is to make it use the max value from one of the specific keys for all the charts.

```
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()                                                      
//  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.n; })])                    
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.filter(d => d.name === "Helen"), e => +e.n)])       
    .range([ height, 0 ]);                                                      
  svg.append("g")                                                               
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));
```

I think I want it to filter d.name against the CURRENT-CHART key (whatever it might be) rather than a specific one (like "Helen" above), but can't figure out how to do it.  Is it some feature of nesting that I haven't found yet?  Something amazingly simple that I can't see??

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built a demo for you, i hope you are looking for something like this. Please let me know if there is any issue.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 210 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 210 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/5_OneCatSevNumOrdered.csv", function(data) {

  // group the data: I want to draw one line per group
  var sumstat = d3.nest() // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
    .key(function(d) { return d.name;})
    .entries(data);

  // What is the list of groups?
  allKeys = sumstat.map(function(d){return d.key})
  
  // Add X axis --> it is a date format
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }))
    .range([ 0, width ]);
    
    // color palette
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(allKeys)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999'])


  // Add an svg element for each group. The will be one beside each other and will go on the next row when no more room available
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .selectAll("uniqueChart")
    .data(sumstat)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .each(multiple);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(3));

  
  // Add titles
  svg
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("y", -5)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(function(d){ return(d.key)})
    .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
    
    function multiple(item) {
       var svg = d3.select(this);
        
          var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(item.values, function(d) { return +d.n; })])
      .range([height, 0]);
      
      svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));
    
      var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(+d.year); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(+d.n); });
    
    // Draw the line
  svg
    .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.9)
      .attr("d", line(item.values))
    }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks!